# msbuild copies whole drive

Tags: msbuild, teamcity

Would really like help with this.

I'm running Team City, have setup a build config, it builds fine. I added a deploy parameter, and that functions almost correctly. The thing is it's trying to deploy my entire c-drive!

This is the config for it:

```
<Target Name="DeployApp">
    <Message Text="Copying application files..." />
    <ItemGroup>
        <ApplicationFiles Include="$(ApplicationOutputDirectory)\**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ApplicationFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(DestinationPath)\%        (RecursiveDir)"/>
</Target>
```

Any help on how to make it only copy the built project to the server?

Comment: What is `$(ApplicationOutputDirectory)` set to?

Answer (score 0):

If `$(ApplicationOutputDirectory)` isn't set, the Include statement will resolve to `\**\*.*`, which is the entire current drive (in this case, your C drive)

Comment: Agreed.  Most common issue.

Comment: I accidentally did this with a DELETE one time.  That was a fun day.  Forturnately I had $(BaseWorkingDirectory)$(SomeSubFolder)  and only SomeSubFolder was empty.